# Convergence of Variance of a Ratio

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**GIVEN**: $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(A_i)=\infty$, $A_i$ are pairwise independent.

**PROVE**: $Var(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{1}_{A_i}}{\mathbb{E}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{1}_{A_i})})\rightarrow 0$

**ATTEMPT**: Set $T_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{1}_{A_i}$. To prove: $Var(\frac{T_n}{E[T_n]})\rightarrow 0$. Since $A_i$ are pairwise independent, we have $Var[T_n]\leq E[T_n].$ Now, $\mathbb{E}\frac{T_n}{E[T_n]} = \frac{\sum\mathbb{P}(A_i)}{\mathbb{E}\sum\mathbb{P}(A_i)}$. How to show $\mathbb{E}(\frac{T_n}{E[T_n]})^2\rightarrow (\mathbb{E}(\frac{T_n}{E[T_n]}))^2$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asked to prove $\operatorname{Var}(T_n/ET_n)\to 0$.  Recall that for any random variable $X$ and any constant $c$, $\operatorname{Var}(cX)=c^2 \operatorname{Var}(X).$ But
 $\operatorname{Var}(T_n/ET_n)=\operatorname{Var}(T_n)/(ET_n)^2,$ which is less than $ET_n/(ET_n)^2=1/ET_n$.  So if you could show $ET_n\to\infty$ you would be done.

Comment: You would then get 1/0. How would that help? Or do I need to show ETn goes to infinity?

Comment: Stupid typo on my part.  As you said, you want to show $ET_n\to\infty$/

Comment: Also, could you explain the step: Var(Tn/ETn)=Var(Tn)/(ETn)2

Comment: And how to show ETn would go to infinity? Hints?

Comment: You will have to work out a formula for $ET_n$ in terms of the given problem data.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see it. The probabilities are infinite but in Tn we are considering a finite number of terms. Do you mean I have to use any inequality? Thanks!

Comment: What is $ET_1$ in terms of the $A_i$?

Comment: That'll be P(A1). So are you saying in the limit n goes to infinity, since the probabilities are infinite, ETn would be infinite, right?

Comment: $ET_n = \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i)$, yes.

Answer (score 0):

We have to show that $\frac {Var(T_n)} {{E(T_n)}^{2}} \to 0$. By definition of variance this becomes $\frac {E\{(T_n)^{2}\}} {{E(T_n)}^{2}} \to 1$. Expand ${T_n}^{2}$ and use independence. Use the fact that  $\sum_1^n {P(A_i})^{2} \leq \sum_1^n {P(A_i)}$ and ht proof reduces to showing that  $\frac {\sum_1^n {P(A_i)}} {({{\sum_1^n {P(A_i)}}})^{2}} \to 0$ which is true.